# Irritating CTRL and ESC key in connectbot for android

Tags: ssh, android

I have a galaxy note 10.1 and a physical blue tooth keyboard that comes with it.

I downloaded ConnectBot because I wanted to SSH to my web servers and use VIM to edit html of web pages.

VIM is extremely powerful when I have quick access to the ESC and TAB keys.  However, ConnectBot requires me to tap the screen, which then shows a CTRL and ESC icon at the bottom of the screen.  Then I must tap the CTRL on the screen, then press the letter i on my keyboard in order to submit the TAB character.  This is extremely frustrating because I use TAB a lot to indent my code!

In order to use the ESC key, i have to actually tap the screen, then press the ESC icon that appears on the screen afterwards.  Again, this is extremely frustrating/time consuming.

Is there a way to make ConnectBot treat the TAB key as TAB and CTRL key as CTRL?  Or is there a way for me to re-map these keys?  Or is there an SSH client out there that will work well with bash terminal and VIM (free or paid)?

Comment: Try `JuiceSSH`, __much__ better interface than ConnectBot.  Very usable with bluetooth keyboard. I had same grumbles with ConnectBot myself.

Comment: @lornix Thanks i just tried JuiceSSH.  The only issue i have with it is that the virtual keyboard is always on the screen. I can't find a way to hide it so that it doesn't steal all that valuable screen real estate.  How do i hide the virtual keyboard?

Comment: Oh wait, i found the option to hide the keyboard in juicessh. Tap the terinal screen, then there will be a small keyboard icon just above hte keyboard.  Tap that and it will hide the virtual keyboard.  So now I just need to figure out how to hit the esc key from my physical keyboard.  Right now, i have a "window" icon on my physical keyboard where it is normally the esc key.  Hitting this window icon minimizes the current application and takes you to the home screen.  So what's the equivalent of the esc key on my physical keyboard?

Comment: I use `Hackers Keyboard` on my tablet, full keyboard layout, arrow keys and everything.  You _could_ use CTRL-[ to emulate ESC.  My bluetooth keyboard is not 'modified' for Android, so I've got the full set of keys (well, all squished up into a small form-factor keyboard).  Perhaps JuiceSSH might allow remapping keys?  A crafty remapping of keys in your shell might allow a lesser used keystroke to become your ESC key. (See man page for `readline`)

Comment: Whoops, readline probably won't work with vim.  Possible to remap keys through dumpkeys/loadkeys, but they tend to be machine global, not per-user.  Was thinking maybe ctrl-b could be remapped to ESC.  Hmmm, feature request to author of JuiceSSH?

Comment: @lornix Actually, I came here because I experience the problem in JuiceSSH that the escape key from a bluetooth keyboard causes JuiceSSH to get backgrounded in favor of the home screen. How do I make that not occur?

Answer (score 2):

I'm testing this with my Android 4.4.2 tablet, using Connectbot with my LG Rolly bluetooth keyboard, and I've got full use of CTRL, TAB, ESC, etc.

Also, if a soft keyboard will suffice, TerminalIDE replaces the stock Android keyboard with a custom keyboard, complete with CTRL, ALT, ESC, FN, DEL, and yes, TAB. It even has arrow keys! Yes, it will work not only in TerminalIDE, but also in ConnectBot.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en
[image]